# How to use one variable in two middlewares nodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, nodes, middleware

I am trying to use one variable in two middlewares but it says ( is not defined )

example:

```
//1st middleware

app.use((req, res, next) =>{
    contentType = req.headers['content-type'];
    if(contentType === 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'){
        next();
    }
})

//2nd middleware

app.use({
)
```

this is just an example so kindly tell me how would I make ( contentType ) as an accessible variable from the 2nd middleware?

Thanks alot

Comment: Just do it? If there is a specific piece of data then make sure it is in a global scope otherwise keep it locally scoped and you can just do it? Like... I don't think I get this question. If this doesn't answer your question then I would suggest editing your question and make it more clear.

Answer (score 1):

Here you go, mate. basically, the expressJWT() function returns a middleware that takes 3 parameters, req, res, and next which is used to go to the next middleware, so what I did is that I used the parameters with expressJWT.

```
//1st middleware

app.use((req, res, next) =>{
    req.contentType = req.headers['content-type'];
    if(req.contentType === 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'){
        next();
    }
})

//2nd middleware

app.use((req, res, next) => expressJWT({
    secret: jwk.expressJwtSecret({
        jwksUri: req.contentType
    }),
})(req, res, next))
```

Comment: Yep! This is the best solution for this I guess.